# Streaming a file to localhost - getting TS errors

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to stream a mp4 file to local host. I can get it going but my streaming platform is detecting TR101 errors and cannot sync to the TS

Command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i <input.mp4> -v 0 -map 0 -codec copy -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:7000
```

TR101 stream analyser Priority errors

[image]

Comment: `-avoid_negative_ts make_zero` or `auto` instead of `make_zero`.  I think this only works encoding, but I'm not certain.  You may need `-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -avoid_negative_ts make_zero` Use `.mkv`, not `.mp4`.